Curl operator for PDE system in 2D
Consider the following parabolic system in 2D:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 u + \nabla \times ( u \times f),
$$
with suitable boundary conditions and an initial state. In this equation, $ u = (u_1, u_2)$ is the unknown, and $f = (f_1, f_2)$ is a given vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
It is known that the curl operator in 2D applied to $ f $ results in the scalar $ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}$. The question is: how can we represent the system above component-wise? What are the components of the vector $\nabla \times ( u \times f) $ in this case?
Thank you in advance.

Have you tried searching curl of cross product?

I hadn't idea. Thanks a lot.

Perhaps the notation is confusing you. The curl of a 2D vector field $(f_1,f_2)$ equals
$$
\partial_x f_2 - \partial_y f_1
$$
The curl of a 2D scalar field $g$ equals
$$
( -\partial_y g, \partial_x g )
$$
So $\nabla \times \nabla \times f$ must equal
$$
\nabla \times ( \partial_x f_2 - \partial_y f_1 )
=
\Big(\;
-\partial_x \partial_y f_2 + \partial_y \partial_y f_1
,\;\;
\partial_x \partial_x f_2 - \partial_y \partial_x f_1
\;\Big)
$$

Thank you sir..
